# Unable to access base class methods in derived class when using method decorators in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, decorator, typescript-decorator

Can someone help me understand following things as when I am using method decorator in TS -

- Why Base class method `base` is not callable in Derived class?
- Why Base class property `val` is `undefined` even though it is being initialized through Derived class constructor?
- If we convert base to a non-arrow function it is callable in Derived class.
- When I did step through debugging, I found out that the value present in target of decorator (t: any) is instance of Base class and not Derived class and not sure why it is happening.

I have added inline comments in code to highlight parts I am referring to, any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#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-QoQ38-Hwx3JcUYFpIxhxgAAVUljkmYh3CnetkHUaEzwva8CmAiwzQtMIrXVW1zlLcChxHGCp3gxDjjlWBkNQuh0KvIlYIsP9SzArhViRIJYFuYJcDABBwk9b1vjwfx+KgCxX27MFUyghBoDzIA) if someone want's to have a look at trans-compiled code, play around and see the error for themselves).

#### Code

```js
const decorator = (val: string) => {
  return function (t: any, pk: any, d: any) {
    console.log("decorator val " + val)
    const ow = d.value
    d.value = (props: any) => {
      console.log({t, d})
      console.log("decorator ", { props })
      return ow.call(t, props)
    }
  }
}

abstract class Base {
  protected val: string
  protected abstract abstractFn(val: string): void

  protected constructor(val: string) {
    this.val = val
  }

  protected base = (val: string) => {
    console.log("base " + val)
  }

  protected nonArrowFunctionBase(val: string) {
    console.log("nonArrowFunctionBase " + val)
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public constructor(val: string = 'default') {
    super(val)
  }

  @decorator("world")
  public abstractFn(val: string) {
    // this.val is returning undefined even though it is initialized, why?
    console.log('derived:abstractFn ' + val + ' baseval ' + this.val) 

    // This call is working, why?
    this.nonArrowFunctionBase(val)

    // This call is not working, why?
    this.base(val) 
  }
}

const test = new Derived()
test.abstractFn('Test')
```

#### Output

```
[LOG]: "decorator val world" 
[LOG]: {
  "t": {},
  "d": {
    "writable": true,
    "enumerable": false,
    "configurable": true
  }
} 
[LOG]: "decorator ",  {
  "props": "Test"
} 
[LOG]: "derived:abstractFn Test baseval undefined" // Why `this.val` is undefined?
[LOG]: "nonArrowFunctionBase Test" // Why non arrow function is callable?
[ERR]: this.base is not a function  // Why `this.base(val)` call fails?
```

I want to understand when using method decorators, why we're not able access Base class methods/values in Derived class? And how we can make it work with decorators?

Comment: It's because your decorator is buggy. It returns [an arrow function instead a function that can be used as a *method*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an arrow function where you need a proper function:

```
let a = {
  foo(){ console.log('a.foo', {this: this}) /* {this: a} */ }
}
let b = {
  foo: function() { console.log('b.foo', {this: this}) /* {this: b} */ }
}
let c = {
  foo: () => { console.log('c.foo', {this: this}) /* {this: globalThis} */ }
}
```

Remember, arrow functions don't have their own `this`

And the second thing: `t` is not `this`, it's some other object.
You need an actual `this` there:

```
const decorator = (val: string) => {
  return function (t: any, pk: any, d: any) {
    console.log("decorator val " + val)
    const ow = d.value
    d.value = function(props: any) {
      //      ^^^^^^^^
      console.log({t, d})
      console.log("decorator ", { props })
      return ow.call(this, props)
      //             ^^^^
    }
  }
}
```